# Curl to HTTPS stop working with Nginx + php-fpm

Tags: curl, php

When I try to do a curl with https in nginx+php-fpm I get the next error in the php-fpm.log

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 661 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 64.104500 seconds from start
[20-Aug-2014 00:09:43] NOTICE: [pool www] child 670 started
```

Also the Nginx give me a 502 Gateway response.

The simple code :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://www.google.com/');
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Just had the very same weird problem. Happened on my using OS X 10.10.x, Apache 2.2.x and PHP 5.6. Nothing helpful in the errors logs.

Answer (score 6):

Quick answer: Just try to remove and install php.

Long answer:

I had the same issue. I spent all day to fix it.
In this forum was discussion about the same issue:
http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/php-fpm-%D0%B8-https-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.58742/

Unfortunately it is in Russian. Explanation/translation of it: you need to:

- stop php-fpm
- delete php
- install php
- List item

I have used Mac and next commands:

- launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php54.plist
- brew uninstall php54
- brew install --without-apache --with-fpm --with-mysql php54
- launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php54.plist

Comment: I can't thank you enough for saving me what must have been about 8 more hours of banging my head against a wall.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in macOS. For me upgrading brew services fixed the issue.

```
brew update
brew upgrade --cleanup
```

Perhaps there was some inconsistency between extensions. After upgrading everything works correct.